# small database for saving limited number of settings

Tags: c#, asp.net, settings

I'm designing a website for a customer in asp.net c# and he wants to have access to some settings without having to modify the source code.  For example, page meta keywords, some sms and email texts, and some numeric values.  Well, these are always written in code. but I don't know where to save them to make them changeable via a panel while maintaining speed and quality.

Save them in a database? They have different datatypes; In a xml file? I think it will affect speed a lot. What would you suggest?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We normally keep small settings in [appSettings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager.appsettings.aspx) of Web.config. I'm not sure it is  relevant to your question.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="mysetting" value="abcd"/>
    <add key="anothersetting" value="cdef"/>
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

Comment: how can I programmatically give access to user to change settings from panel? wouldn't opening and closing web.config for writing be a problem?

Comment: It is not normal to change setting in web.config from code in runtime. However, you can use another approach which uses app.Config - [Read/Write App.Config File with .NET 2.0](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14744/Read-Write-App-Config-File-with-NET-2-0)

Answer (score 0):

If the data set is small and flat (e.g. non-relational or hierarchical), I would either put the data into your App_Data.xml or Web.config file. A relational database is too much hassle for flat application settings. You can then edit the App_Data file during runtime using just the Xml libraries that come with .NET.

Comment: the customer wants to edit settings from admin panel. and won't xml files speed get me in trouble?

Comment: if it's tens of thousands of options stored in xml yes.  If it's a relatively small number, xml is fine.

Comment: @AshkanMobayenKhiabani not if you keep the contents of the xml file in memory at start up. Then whenever someone wants to edit the file, update your in-memory state and then write that out to the file. Anyways, xml I/O is plenty fast--even without caching-- unless you are talking about hundreds/thousands of users updating this page. The overhead of thread safety will probably be the slowest part.

Answer (score 0):

One possible database solution would be to use [ServiceStack.OrmLite](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite) with SQLite database. Your settings file will be the POCO. Query/Update happens in one line.

Another solution would be to use LINQ2XML - the overhead for writing & reading a small file from time to time is insignificant.

Comment: I am not disagreeing entirely, but .... nothing with the word "ORM" in it is simple.